# Trying to Implement Gradient Descent Algorithm with Fixed Step Size

Tags: algorithm, matlab, gradient

I am trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm with fixed step size on MATLAB.\

```
syms x1 x2 x3 x4
f(x1,x2,x3,x4) = (x1+10*x2)^2 + 5*(x3-x4)^2 + (x2-2*x3)^4 + 10*(x1-x4)^4 ;
grad_f = gradient(f);
xk = [3;-1;0;1];
while euclidian(grad_f(xk(1),xk(2),xk(3),xk(4)),4) > 0.01
    xk = xk- 0.001*grad_f(xk(1),xk(2),xk(3),xk(4));
    double(xk)
end
```

This is the main part and the following is the euclidian norm function:

```
function euclidian_norm = euclidian (x,size)
    total = 0;
    for i = 1:size
        total = total + x(i)^2;
    end
    euclidian_norm = sqrt(total);
end
```

But, when I try to run the code, it takes forever compute it. And I don't have any idea why.
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Can anyone try to run the code and tell me if the same problem occurs?

Comment: Try debugging to find out what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame the problem as a vector dot product to take advantage of MATLAB's built-in linear algebra routines, which are much faster than explicit loops:

```
function euclidean_norm = euclidean(x)
    euclidean_norm = x' * x;
end
```

You don't need the `size` parameter (even in your existing code, it would be less error-prone to compute it within the function instead of asking the caller to compute and pass it in).

I would argue that this doesn't even need to be a separate function, but there's no harm in it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the norm function might be the reason of the slowness; therefore, tried by coding my own function. And by the way, if * is used for dot product, how do we do normal matrix multiplication?

Comment: You're welcome :) The dot product *is* normal matrix multiplication (of a row vector by a column vector). BTW if you found my answer helpful, you could upvote and/or mark it accepted.

Comment: Hey, when I implemented the euclidean as you mentioned,  the code still work slowly, faster than before tho. Is there anything I can make to make the code even faster?

Comment: You could just compute `grad_f(xk(1),xk(2),xk(3),xk(4)` just once per iteration instead of twice. Otherwise, not that I can see. I just noticed you seem to be using some kind of symbolic computation (`syms...`). I'm not familiar with that, but it might be faster to just compute with vectors and matrices directly. Also what makes you expect it to be faster?

Comment: Hey. I figured out the reason. The reason is the symbolic expression. When I took the symbolic expressions out, it become much more faster. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)